Compare account field value from 30 days ago to today?
I enabled 'track old and new values' for a few fields (app_total_workspaces, app_client_engagements, etc) that track our customers usage data.
I'm trying to create a report that shows me what the app_total_workspaces value was 30 days ago, and what it is today, and ideally the difference between the two (%). I'd also like to have it give me the data on the first day of every month.
I'm hoping to create a report with multiple columns that show the previous value and todays value, with each row containing a new Account/customer.
What's the best way to do this? I'm struggling to create this with account history reports.
Edit: I have a report that shows the changes to the field on a day by day basis, but I don't know where it was on a specific date (5/1/24 , 6/1/24, etc) or on a rolling basis. I need to be able to quickly look at the columns to see the differences, instead of digging through the rows.

I'm struggling to create this with account history reports. - what have you tried, where are you stuck? Please edit your question and show your attempt.

Good question. Updated!

Row-level formula might work: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/rd-summary-formulas/rd-row-level-formulas. For certain report types, row-level formulas aren't available, a formula field is a fallback.

Would Reporting Snapshots meet your requirements?
